# Jenkins shell fetching secret txt

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a secret txt and want to pass the Variables in the Jenkins Shell script (Not the Pipeline)
Need help on this

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'API_TOKEN_ID', variable: 'TOKEN_VALUE')])
```

the above works in shell script inside the pipeline, but want to execute this in "Execute Shell" mode in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this : https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/

If it’s a token you can put it as an env variables